# React functional component inside a loop calls api only returns the response for last element passed on api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, closures

Parent component

```
  data.map(eachData => (
     <ChildComponent
     key={eachData.id}
     child={eachData}
     />
  ))
```

Child Component

**props.getChildData({id: id}); code calls Redux action and store it in a reducer**

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
const [id, setId] = React.useState(props.eachData.id)
useEffect(() => {
    let handler
    (function () {
      handler = setTimeout(() => {   
        props.getChildData({id: id})
      }, 1000)
    })();
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler)
    }
  }, [id])

}
```

Api calls are happening and verified in the network tab. **Redux store returns only the api response has last api response**

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly accessing the id in child component.
The id is inside props.child and not props.eachData
So change the useState to access id like this:

```
const [id, setId] = React.useState(props.child.id);
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: No. it didn't work. here the issue is looping react child component, and child component has an api call inside useEffect()